# Sticking a div and scaling according to the browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I am learning the basics of web development.
I would like to make the position of a div depend on the dimensions of the browser window. I would also like this div to scale.

The easiest way to demonstrate this would be with images (it's all about the 'radio panel'):
[Intended appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Nqk.png)
[Scaled down the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X95FN.png)
The code I have written so far:

'panel' is the object I want to manipulate.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="panel">  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    background-image: url('tlo.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}

#panel{
    background-image: url('radio.png');
    position:relative;
    width: 49.7%;
    height: 30vh;
    /*border: 5px solid red;  */
    top:35.1%;
    left:23.9%;

}
```

[Panel with red border should fit in the green border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ycdg.png)
I've tried to find solutions on the Internet, but I don't even know quite how I'm supposed to describe it in a specialized way.

Comment: Look up media queries.

Comment: @Levidps I would like the div's dimensional changes to match the frame in the screenshot even after changing the browser window by 1 pixel

Comment: So you want the larger background image to change size, but the smaller image to stay the same size?

Comment: I would like this smaller image to fit all the time with dimensions and scale into the green border (which is where the radio is mounted in the car): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ycdg.png <- In this screenshot, the browser window is shrunken and has props close to square

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: (put it in head)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And if it will not work as you expected it to work, then you can read something about media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the `#main` div to `100vh`.

```css
#main{
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Zinnia_elegans_with_Bombus_01.JPG/1200px-Zinnia_elegans_with_Bombus_01.JPG?20070924151254');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}

#panel{
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Halictus_bee_on_flower-2.jpg/1200px-Halictus_bee_on_flower-2.jpg?20070515152433');
    position:relative;
    width: 49.7%;
    height: 30vh;
    /*border: 5px solid red;  */
    top:35.1%;
    left:23.9%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="panel">  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after shrinking the browser window, it continues as in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ycdg.png / Panel with red border should fit in the green border